# How are subtypes and generics resolved in CDI/Weld?

Tags: generics, jakarta-ee, cdi

I work in Wildfly 8.2.1 Final which runs Weld 2.2.6 Final.

Given

```
@Entity
public class Fruit{ ... }

@Entity
public class Apple extends Fruit{ ... }


public interface Repository<T extends Identifiable> { ... }


public interface Identifiable { String getId(); }
```

and

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FruitCDIDelegateRepository implements Repository<Fruit>, SearchableRepository<Fruit> { @EJB private FruitRepository repo; }

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Typed(FruitRepository.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class FruitRepository extends PersistenceRepository<Fruit> implements SearchableRepository<Fruit, FruitCriteria> {
```

The last two Repositories are a construct straight out of the book
*Continous Enterprise Development in Java* by Andrew Lee Rubinger and
Aslak Knidsen. It is a workaround to help EJB and CDI work
together. In the book they write

> This EJB is @Typed to a specific type to avoid being picked up by
>   CDI under Repository due to limitations/error in the CDI EJB
>   interactions. A EJB Beans is always resolved as Repository, which means
>   two EJBs that implements the Repository interface both respond to
>   the InjectionPoint @Inject Repository and making the InjectionPoint
>   ambiguous.
>
> As a WorkAround we wrap the EJB that has Transactional properties in CDI bean
>   that can be used by the Type system. The EJB is to be considered a internal
>   implementation detail. The CDI Type provided by the ConferenceCDIDelegateRepository
>   is the real Repository api.

Other classes should be negligible in this context.

Should I not be able to declare

```
@Inject
Repository<Apple> repository;
```

in a class and obtain a `FruitRepository` (`CDIDelegate` kind)? A similar case

```
@Inject
Repository<Fruit> repository;
```

In the same environment yields the expected object.

Comment: Why not @Inject FruitRepository fruitRepository? You can inject CDI<->EJB

Comment: Hmmm. Did I wrap around this too many times today? I must clear my head and I get back to you. At the moment, I must say, it seems like this would be the case and that your suggestion is spot on. Off to clear my head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the @Statless Repository without wrapper.

```
@RequestScoped
public class Service {

    @Inject
    FruitRepository fruitRepository;

    public void saveFruit(Fruit fruit){
        fruitRepository.save(fuit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight. I had taken too many turns around the generic type parameters and being too smart (not the first time). I absolutely should have seen that hours ago. "hanging my head"